# After payment auto return main website from payson.se?

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment

I am using payson payment getaway for my eCommerce website. It's working fine, but I want when user use this and payment is successful then it's return auto my website. now it's come when user click on 'Return to shop' button.

Please guide or give me suggestion for it.

[image]

thanks.

Comment: does the service provide options for redirecting to specific URL in your website??? usually payment gateways have such functionality, try looking into documentation of the service.

Comment: most payment gateways provide (and require) a `returnUrl` parameter, isn't this one doing it ? haven't you found info about that in their API/dev' center ?